# Animate a Child-Target

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

*i have some issues to animate a child-target.
I've a Grid with two Buttons. If i Enter with the Mouse into the Grid, i want to animate the Buttons with doubleanimation, different than the parent element (Grid). Is this possible?

What I intend to do is for the buttons to have a different animate than the grid when I mouse over the grid
Thats my try:*

```
        <Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Key="GrowMeUp">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="5" To="0" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
    
<Grid Style="{StaticResource GrowMeUp}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btn_FileUpload" Name="Button1" Background="White" Height="50" Width="400" Content="Save"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_FileDownload" Name="Button2" Background="White" Height="50" Width="400" Content="Save"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: where is Button1?

Comment: You should give more code and give us the error you are trying so far.

Comment: i added more code @JialeXue-MSFT